# Set Campaign Member custom field in Pardot

Tags: campaign, pardot, campaign-member

I have a requirement to set a custom field while creating a Campaign Member from a Pardot form using "***Add to Campaign***". Currently the only field that can be set is the standard ***status*** field.

The invitee for example can fill in his/her ***+1*** for the event and this should also be stored in the campaign member.

Any idea on how to achieve this? I am relatively new to Pardot.

Comment: +1 invitee should  be its own campaign member, else there's no point. Good read: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/download/file/0693A000006UxfcQAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be a tricky thing. Technically, one could argue that the +1 didn't explicitly give you permission to email them, so you may not want them as their own Prospect record.

How we've solved this in the past for our clients is to have the +1 information as custom fields on the Prospect record (so we can see Sally invited Bob).

Next, sync this information to Salesforce, then use Salesforce Automation to create/update the CampaignMember record to stamp additional details on the CampaignMember.

Getting the order of operations right is important, given there's a Salesforce Sync involved and the CampaignMember record may/may not already be there.